# Google Cloud Platform（GCP）の解約について

Tags: google-cloud

GCPの無料枠を試しました。自分には必要なさそうなのと課金が怖いので、
・プロジェクトのシャットダウン
・請求先アカウントの閉鎖
をしたのですが、これで課金されることはなくなるでしょうか。

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 2):

こんにちは、はじめまして

はい、経験上ですが、請求先アカウントを閉鎖されれば請求がくることはなくなると思います。下記のヘルプをご確認ください。

https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/close-account?hl=ja
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account?hl=ja

もし何か不測の事態がおきた場合は、サポートに連絡をすれば対応してもらえると思います。

https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/?hl=ja&visit_id=637310014086026764-1072335246&rd=1